# Stop Alertdialog to automatically scroll up?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-linearlayout, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog popping with DatePicker and TimePicker on it. The AlertDialog is quite long so you have to scroll down to fill everything. However, every time I click somewhere the view will automatically jump back to the top of the AlertDialog, making it impossible to peacefully click on the Timeicker.
Is there any way to stop it from scrolling back up by itself every time something is clicked?

Here is the code :

```
        private void AddEventDialog(ListView listview, Marker marker, ArrayAdapter<string> adapter)
    {
        TextView name_tv = new TextView(this);
        EditText name_et = new EditText(this);
        TextView start_date_tv = new TextView(this);
        TextView end_date_tv = new TextView(this);
        DatePicker start_date_picker = new DatePicker(this);
        DatePicker end_date_picker = new DatePicker(this);
        TimePicker start_time_picker = new TimePicker(this);
        TimePicker end_time_picker = new TimePicker(this);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
        AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


        name_tv.Text = "Nom :";
        name_tv.TextSize = 18.0f;

        start_date_tv.Text = "Début :";
        start_date_tv.TextSize = 18.0f;

        end_date_tv.Text = "Fin :";
        end_date_tv.TextSize = 18.0f;

        ll.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        ll.SetPadding(30, 0, 30, 0);
        ll.CanScrollVertically(1);
        ll.AddView(name_tv);
        ll.AddView(name_et);

        ll.AddView(start_date_tv);
        ll.AddView(start_date_picker);
        ll.AddView(start_time_picker);
        ll.AddView(end_date_tv);
        ll.AddView(end_date_picker);
        ll.AddView(end_time_picker);

        sv.AddView(ll);

        ad.SetTitle("Ajout d'un événement");
        ad.SetView(sv);
        ad.SetPositiveButton("Ajouter", (senderAlert, args) => {
            ToastUser("Événement ajouté !", ToastLength.Long);

            DateTime dts = start_date_picker.DateTime.AddHours(start_time_picker.Hour);
            dts = start_date_picker.DateTime.AddMinutes(start_time_picker.Minute);
            DateTime dte = end_date_picker.DateTime.AddHours(end_time_picker.Hour);
            dte = end_date_picker.DateTime.AddMinutes(end_time_picker.Minute);

            EventCreation(name_et.Text, GetPlaceFromMarker(marker).Id, marker.Snippet, start_date_picker.DateTime, end_date_picker.DateTime);
            adapter.Add(name_et.Text);
            listview.Adapter = adapter;
            dialog_child.Dismiss();
            ManageEventsDialog(marker);
        });
        ad.SetNegativeButton("Annuler", (senderAlert, args) => {
        });
        ad.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's happening because of your edit-text, Your edit-text always start focus ,try to disable that first with:
In Manifest on desire activity set this

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"